# Trying to end a loop with "0" from user

Tags: java

The assignment is about trying to get the prime numbers from what the user inputs and I'm trying to end the loop by the user entering 0

```
/*
 Natasha Shorrock
 Assignment A4
 10/20/16
 */
package a4;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class MainApp {

        static boolean isPrimeOptimized(int candidate) {
        if (candidate < 2) {
            return false;
        }//if
        if (candidate % 2 == 0) {
            //divisble by 2 with no remainder
            //is not prime
            return false;
        }//if
        int divisor = 3;
        while (divisor < candidate / 2) {
            if (candidate % divisor == 0) {
                return false;// this is not prime
            }//if
            divisor = divisor + 2;
        }//while
        return true;
    }//isPrime

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        while (true) {
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Enter 2 numbers or zero to exit: ");

            //ask the user for low and high
            //range of [prime numbers to generate
            int low = sc.nextInt();
            int high = sc.nextInt();

            int candidate = low;
            int count = 0;
            while (candidate <= high) {
                if (isPrimeOptimized(candidate)) {
                    //if prime print
                    count = count + 1;
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println(count + " " + candidate);

                }//if
                candidate = candidate + 1;
            }//while

        }//while (true)

    }//class

}//classMainApp
```

Comment: She only asks for one number, so if she entered `0`, only `low` would be populated and it would wait for `high`. So the if should be between the two scans and should only check `low`

Answer (score 0):

Since you only ask for one number to exit, `0`, only `low` would be populated and it would wait for `high`. So the `if` should be between the two scans and should only check `low`

Add an `if` statement under `low` to check if it is a 0.

```
int low = sc.nextInt();
if(low == 0){
    break;
}
```

Comment: Which low are you referring to?

Comment: @ShreyasSarvothama `break` will exit out of the `while(true)` loop and continue on with the program, which is what I imagine OP wants to do. In this case, the program will end when that loop is broken, but it does leave room to do other things afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,  even if the user enter 0 you are forcing them to enter two numbers:

```
int low = sc.nextInt();
int high = sc.nextInt();
```

I would suggest you do the following in your code:

```
int low = sc.nextInt();
if(low==0){
   return 0;
} else{

   int high = sc.nextInt();
   //rest of your code and while loop
}
```